# How can I recursively configure svn status to hide ignored files?

Tags: svn

My directory structure looks like the following:

```
project/
    app1/
    app2/
    settings.py
```

From within the `project` directory, I ran `svn propedit svn:ignore .`  This only ignore files from within project director excluding its sub-directories.  I can run the svn ignore again from within each of the folder and it will work. Is there an internal svn command or option which can recursively do it for me or should I resort to a script to perform the ignore within each sub-folders of my project?

I've set my ignored files to be:

```
*.pyc
*.swp
```

However, whenever I do a `svn status`, I still see the above files.  Is there a way to tell `svn status` to hide ignored files recursively?

Comment: `svn status` does hide ignored files. How did you set those files to be ignored?

Comment: Have you checked in the change to ignore? I'm not sure it will work until you do.

Comment: I've edited my question for more clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`svn propedit` only works on one target at a time.  [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) has an option to apply properties recursively, but if you’re not using it or another GUI that has that option, you would have to do it with a script.

However, what you should *really* do is set your `global-ignores` to ignore the two file patterns you mentioned.  According to [the most recent documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.confarea), `*.pyc` and `*.swp` are included in the default ignores for Subversion 1.6, but you can add them if your `config` file doesn’t have them.

The location of your `config` file is platform-dependent; see the above documentation link.  `global-ignores` is in the `miscellany` section.

Comment: Documenation link is dead. I believe this is the current version and location of interest. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.props.special.ignore Relevant section - "On Unix-like systems, this area appears as a directory named .subversion in the user's home directory. On Win32 systems, Subversion creates a folder named Subversion, typically inside the Application Data area of the user's profile directory (which, by the way, is usually a hidden directory). "

Comment: In Windows type %APPDATA% into the explorer address bar to be taken there.

Answer (score 2):

Only problem with the global-ignores is that you need a file extension. In some programs there are files without an extension (or there are just many extensions). An example are the tmp files in CakePHP.

I fixed this by (in Linux bash shell):

```
cd app/tmp
for a in `find . -type d |grep -v svn`; do svn propset svn:ignore '*' $a; done
```