# svn (subversion) ignore specific file types in all sub-directories, configured on root?

Tags: svn

I have the following folder structure, and I would like for svn to ignore all eclipse files (*`.classpath`* and *`.project`* and *`.settings`*) in sub-projects

```
main-project/
  sub-1/.classpath
  sub-2/.classpath
  sub-3/part1/.classpath
  sub-3/part2/.classpath
```

Is there any way of configuring the `.svn` in the "main-project" to `svn:ignore **/**.classpath?`

So I dont have to edit it in every single sub-folder?

Comment: See the related SO question [How can I recursively configure svn status to hide ignored files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594933/how-can-i-recursively-configure-svn-status-to-hide-ignored-files).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the answer I was looking for is:

```
vim ~/.subversion/config
```

scroll down to 'global-ignores':

```
global-ignores = *.classpath
```

The answer came from here:

[How can I recursively configure svn status to hide ignored files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594933/how-can-i-recursively-configure-svn-status-to-hide-ignored-files)

Comment: Global config was in `%AppData%\Roaming\Subversion` for me. Thank you @Joey from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2694934/1108891

Comment: thanks! I have this(`subfolder/.classpath`) in .svnignore, then execute `svn propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore .` it did not work, that is when execute `svn st` still could see  `subfolder/.classpath`. So I use your way and it works

Answer (score 7):

Use the `--recursive` (`-R`) flag on `svn propset` and set the `svn:ignore` so that it is applied recursively to every sub-folder:

`svn propset svn:ignore -R <mask> <directory or . for current>`

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html