# Set svn:ignore recursively for a directory structure

Tags: bash, svn, sed, awk, svnignore

I have imported a huge hierarchy of maven projects into IntelliJ idea, now idea has created .iml projects on all different levels. I would like to svn:ignore these files.

There are several similar questions, for example this one: [svn (subversion) ignore specific file types in all sub-directories, configured on root?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6878673/342852)

However: the answer is always to apply `svn:ignore` with the `--recursive` flag. That's not what I am looking for, I just want to ignore the files I created, not set a property on the hundreds of directories underneath.

Basically, what I have is the output of

```
svn status | grep .iml
```

which looks like this:

```
?       foo/bar/bar.iml
?       foo/baz/phleem.iml
?       flapp/flapp.iml
```

etc.

What I would like to do is for each entry `dir/project.iml` to add `svn:ignore *.iml` to `dir`. I am guessing I have to pipe the above grep to `sed` or `awk` and from there to `svn`, but I am at a total loss as to the exact sed or awk command on one hand and the exact svn command (with which I won't override existing svn:ignore values) on the other hand.

Update: what I am also not looking for are solutions based on `find`, because possibly there are projects in this hierarchy where .iml files are in fact committed and I wouldn't want to interfere with those projects, so I'm looking to add the property only for .iml files my IDE has created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set up your client to globally ignore given file extensions. Just add

```
global-ignores = *.iml
```

into your Subversion config file.

**Update:** If you want to only ignore iml files in the directories involved, you can try

```
svn status | grep '^\?.*\.iml' | sed 's=^? *=./=;s=/[^/]*$==' | xargs svn propset svn:ignore '*.iml'
```

Comment: The `grep` part of the last line would be a bit safer with the question mark escaped and the dot included in the pattern: `grep '^\?.*\.iml'`.

Comment: For completeness’ sake: SVN config lives in `~/.subversion/config`.

Comment: A warning is in place for `svn propset`. It will overwrite, not add to, existing properties.